# Annotating a function assigned to a variable in TypeScript and TSLint

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have these 3 functions, which are nearly identical except for some very minor differences:

```
function toInt1(x: string): number { return parseInt(x, 10); }

const toInt2 = function (x: string): number { return parseInt(x, 10); };

const toInt3 = (x: string): number => parseInt(x, 10);
```

Now I'm new to TypeScript, but in JS land, I prefer the third because it is most concise and most restrictive (no `this`, no hoisting of the function name).

However when I use tslint with this rule (which on the surface seems reasonable, but maybe I'm wrong about that...):

```
"typedef": [
  true,
  "call-signature",
  "parameter",
  "arrow-parameter",
  "property-declaration",
  "variable-declaration",
  "member-variable-declaration"
],
```

I get these errors about the `toInt2` and `toInt3`:

```
expected variable-declaration: 'toInt2' to have a typedef
expected variable-declaration: 'toInt3' to have a typedef
```

Seems I can fix it by duplicating all the types:

```
const toInt2: (x: string) => number = function (x: string): number { return parseInt(x, 10); };
const toInt3: (x: string) => number = (x: string): number => parseInt(x, 10);
```

However this is very verbose and unappealing. Is this really the best way to do things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transpiler wants to assign a type to each name (variable). In general, it can figure out (infer) this type from an assignment:

```
// const x: number = 10;
const x = 10; 
// const y: string = 'foo';
const y = 'foo';
// const z: (a: string) => number = (a: string) => parseInt(a);
const z = (a: string) => parseInt(a);
```

This rule `'variable-declaration'` makes sure that you are not letting the transpiler infer the type, but you are explicitly writing the type signatures for any `var`, `let` or `const` declaration (as far as I can see in the docs). This can improve readability (the reader of your code knows the static type of each variable without further investigation), but at the cost of writing the type signatures for all variables.

Now to solve this, you have 2 options:

1. Disable the rule [inline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint#rule-flags), wherever appropriate
2. Write a [custom rule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint#writing-custom-rules) for this